# delete specific number of letters from pandas column using values from second column, Python

Tags: python, pandas

my df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['elisabeth','adamms','jorhgen'], 'B':[2,2,3]})
```

i need to delete ends of strings in column A , in column B there is amount how many letters i should delete.
normally i would use this code:

```
df['A']=df['A'].str[:-2] # to delete for first row , two letters from right side.
```

expected result:

```
           A  B
0  elisabe    2
1     adam    2
2    jorh     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `zip`:

```
df['A']= [a[:-b] for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]
```

Or [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.A[:-x.B], axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
         A  B
0  elisabe  2
1     adam  2
2     jorh  3
```

Comment: you are my savior again hah, i was wondering how to use apply in this case :O

Answer (score 1):

Not the best tho:

```
>>> it = iter(df['A'].tolist())
>>> df['A'] = [next(it)[:-i] for i in df['B']]
>>> df
         A  B
0  elisabe  2
1     adam  2
2     jorh  3
>>>
```